# How to use same shadow DOM on different places with different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm using a pre-made web component called `rssapp-feed`. I want to use this in 2 different places one standard

Like this, this is what the original shadow DOM markup looks like:

[image]

and one with modifier class `rssapp-feed--sidebar`.

Like this:

[image]

I have added this modifier class through javascript.

```
var a = document.querySelector('rssapp-feed')
       .shadowRoot.querySelector('.rssapp-feed')
       .classList.add('rssapp-feed--sidebar');
```

The problem is I just want the modifier class to be added in one of the web components only. By adding a modifier class like this it's been adding on both the places. And by this whatever styles I give to modifier class it applies to both of those. Like if I want to set `display: none` to the last element with the class `card-root` it affects both the components.

Is there any way to use the same web component on two different places with different classes?

Here is the web component that I'm using in my HTML.

```
<rssapp-feed id="i0QRdHCkHgYPGNWs"></rssapp-feed><script src="https://widget.rss.app/v1/feed.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

Here is the example on [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-morning-5xl11c?file=/index.html)

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a better CSS selector to pass to the `querySelector` function. If you have control over the code where `<rssapp-feed></rssapp-feed>` is being added then simply add some unique `class` or `data-*` attribute to it. And then query using it.

Using class:

```html
<rssapp-feed id="i0QRdHCkHgYPGNWs"></rssapp-feed>
 
<!-- Unique selector using class -->
<rssapp-feed id="i0QRdHCkHgYPGNWs" class="sidebar"></rssapp-feed>
```

In your JS code:

```js
// Using class + element selector
document.querySelector('rssapp-feed.sidebar')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('.rssapp-feed')
  .classList.add('rssapp-feed--sidebar');
```

Or using `data-*` attribute:

```html
<rssapp-feed id="i0QRdHCkHgYPGNWs"></rssapp-feed>
 
<!-- Unique selector using data-* attribute -->
<rssapp-feed id="i0QRdHCkHgYPGNWs" data-id="sidebar"></rssapp-feed>
```

In your JS code:

```js
// Using attribute selector
document.querySelector('rssapp-feed[data-id="sidebar"]')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('.rssapp-feed')
  .classList.add('rssapp-feed--sidebar');
```

Finally, if you don't have control over the code, use some nested CSS selector using some parent which is unique to the web-component.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend **any *defined*** Web Component; and **build your own** Web Component on top of it:

Example: You can steal a 52 SVG playing cards Web Component with [this Dev.to Post](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/how-to-cheat-with-web-components-295o)

```html
<component-a>
 Hello Web Component A!
</component-a>

<component-b>
 Hello Web Component B!
</component-b>

<script>
  customElements.define('component-a', 
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() { 
        super()
          .attachShadow({mode:'open'})
          .innerHTML=`<h1 style="color:red"><slot></slot></h1>`; 
    }
  });
  customElements.whenDefined('component-a').then(()=>{
    customElements.define('component-b', 
    class extends customElements.get("component-a") {
      connectedCallback(){
        if (super.connectedCallback) super.connectedCallback();
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector("h1").style.color = "green";
      }
    });
  })
</script>
```